# printing responses returned by ec2.describe_regions() in print

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

Hello everyone I am learning python currently doing some assignment for amazon ec2 with boto3 connecting to instances and launching t2 microinstances via python3 , here is a small code which gives output

```
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')

# Retrieves all regions/endpoints that work with EC2
response = ec2.describe_regions()

print('Regions:', response['Regions'])
```

The code is taken from here  https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/ec2-example-regions-avail-zones.html this is giving me following output

```
Regions: 
[
{'Endpoint': 'ec2.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com', 'RegionName': 'ap-south-1'}, 
{'Endpoint': 'ec2.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com', 'RegionName': 'eu-west-3'}, 
{'Endpoint': 'ec2.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com', 'RegionName': 'eu-west-2'}, 
{'Endpoint': 'ec2.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com', 'RegionName': 'eu-west-1'},
{'Endpoint': 'ec2.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com', 'RegionName': 'ap-northeast-2'},
{'Endpoint': 'ec2.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com', 'RegionName': 'ap-northeast-1'}, 
{'Endpoint': 'ec2.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com', 'RegionName': 'sa-east-1'}, 
{'Endpoint': 'ec2.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com', 'RegionName': 'ca-central-1'},
{'Endpoint': 'ec2.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com', 'RegionName': 'ap-southeast-1'},
{'Endpoint': 'ec2.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com', 'RegionName': 'ap-southeast-2'}, 
{'Endpoint': 'ec2.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com', 'RegionName': 'eu-central-1'}, 
{'Endpoint': 'ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com', 'RegionName': 'us-east-1'}, 
{'Endpoint': 'ec2.us-east-2.amazonaws.com', 'RegionName': 'us-east-2'},
{'Endpoint': 'ec2.us-west-1.amazonaws.com', 'RegionName': 'us-west-1'}, 
{'Endpoint': 'ec2.us-west-2.amazonaws.com', 'RegionName': 'us-west-2'}
]
```

What  I want to do is one by one print the values in dictionary returned by function ec2.describe_regions() some thing of this sort

```
print (response[0],response[1],response[2])
```

but this gives me keyerror

```
describe_regions2.py", line 9, in <module>
    print (response[0])
KeyError: 0
```

if I do a

```
print (response['Endpoint'])
```

then also I get error

```
describe_regions2.py", line 9, in <module>
    print (response['Endpoint'])
KeyError: 'Endpoint'
>>>
```

How can I get individual element of ec2.describe_regions() I read the documentation here 
https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_regions
which has given an expected output when `print(response)` is used .
Here instead of all the output  I want just a few desired elements returned from dictionary. This is what I am not able to get in code.
Here if I use

```
print (response['Regions'][0]['Endpoint'])
```

I get

```
ec2.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com
```

if I use

```
print (response['Regions'][0])
```

I get `{'Endpoint': 'ec2.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com', 'RegionName': 'ap-south-1'}`

the new code I tried is

```
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')

# Retrieves all regions/endpoints that work with EC2
response = ec2.describe_regions()
c=0
#print('Regions:', response['Regions'])
#for i in response:
#    print ("i= ",i+" response[i]=",response[i])
#    print ("\n")
print ("\nhale luliya\n")
print ("Endpoint="+response['Regions'][0]['Endpoint'])
print ("RegionName="+response['Regions'][0]['RegionName'])
print ("Full response for list[0]"+response['Regions'][0])
```

the last print statement gives error

```
\describe_regions2.py", line 15, in <module>
    print ("Full response for list[0]"+response['Regions'][0])
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "dict") to str
```

How can I iterate over the whole list received in response in a for loop.To print only the desired value?
I am able to do

```
for key,value in response['Regions'][0].items():
    print(key,value)
```

which gives me

```
Endpoint ec2.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com
RegionName ap-south-1
```

**The problem is solved now updating here** 
here the complexity was because `print(type(response['Regions']))` gives 
`<class 'list'>` and `print(type(response['Regions']))` is `<class 'dict'>` and

```
print (type(response))
```

is `<class 'dict'>` so dictionary is also returned inside dictionary a list and another dictionary was being returned. So I was not able to understand.Output of

```
for data in response['Regions']: 
    print(data) 
for key,value in response['ResponseMetadata'].items(): 
    print(key,value)
```

Helped me understand what was being returned

```
{'Endpoint': 'ec2.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com', 'RegionName': 'ap-south-1'}
{'Endpoint': 'ec2.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com', 'RegionName': 'eu-west-3'}
{'Endpoint': 'ec2.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com', 'RegionName': 'eu-west-2'}
{'Endpoint': 'ec2.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com', 'RegionName': 'eu-west-1'}
{'Endpoint': 'ec2.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com', 'RegionName': 'ap-northeast-2'}
{'Endpoint': 'ec2.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com', 'RegionName': 'ap-northeast-1'}
{'Endpoint': 'ec2.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com', 'RegionName': 'sa-east-1'}
{'Endpoint': 'ec2.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com', 'RegionName': 'ca-central-1'}
{'Endpoint': 'ec2.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com', 'RegionName': 'ap-southeast-1'}
{'Endpoint': 'ec2.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com', 'RegionName': 'ap-southeast-2'}
{'Endpoint': 'ec2.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com', 'RegionName': 'eu-central-1'}
{'Endpoint': 'ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com', 'RegionName': 'us-east-1'}
{'Endpoint': 'ec2.us-east-2.amazonaws.com', 'RegionName': 'us-east-2'}
{'Endpoint': 'ec2.us-west-1.amazonaws.com', 'RegionName': 'us-west-1'}
{'Endpoint': 'ec2.us-west-2.amazonaws.com', 'RegionName': 'us-west-2'}
RequestId 221d8d0f-908f-4996-8c88-87b00c5da592
HTTPStatusCode 200
HTTPHeaders {'content-type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8', 'content-length': '2559', 'vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'date': 'Sun, 19 Aug 2018 06:20:40 GMT', 'server': 'AmazonEC2'}
RetryAttempts 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are facing can be debugged by you by using these simple steps.

Whenever you get the response do a `print(type(response))`

- If the output is `str` then it means you need to convert into `json` using the python's own json library.
- If you get output `list`, then you can access it via index like `response[0], response[1]` or maybe loop over it
- If you get output `dict`, then you can access it via name like `response['Endpoint']`

Generally when you are dealing with api data, you need to follow the above steps. There are chances you will get nested level of results as *list of list of dictionary*, or *dictionary of list of dictionary*, or maybe plain string which is can be converted to json.

Update:
You can iterate on a dictionary as follow:

```
data = {'Endpoint': 'ec2.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com', 'RegionName': 'ap-south-1'}
for key,value in data.items():
    print(key , value)
```

Comment: while trying things I did a print (response['Regions'][0]['Endpoint']) gives me some help to find the values I am looking I updated the question.

Comment: I wrote following `for key,value in response['Regions'][0].items():
    print(key,value)` it gives output for `Endpoint=ec2.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com
RegionName=ap-south-1
Endpoint ec2.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com
RegionName ap-south-1` Now how do I iterate over whole list whose individual members are dict

Comment: No. `response['Regions']` is a list, so when you are looping over a list donot write `for key,value in response['Regions']: print(key,value)` instead write `for data in response['Regions']: print(data)`. Kindly follow the three steps to find the type of data using `print(type(response['Regions']))` this will help you better

Comment: yes now I got it 
`for data in response['Regions']:
    print(data)
for key,value in response['ResponseMetadata'].items():
    print(key,value)`

Comment: here the complexity was because `print(type(response['Regions']))` gives `
`<class 'list'>` and `print(type(response['Regions']))` is `<class 'dict'>` and 
`print (type(response))` is `<class 'dict'>` so dictionary is also returned inside dictionary a list and another dictionary was being returned. So I was not able to understand.

Comment: @argo - Good advice on how to figure out how to process a response in Python. Beginning programmers always run into this problem.

Comment: Yes. I too faced such issues, during my early days. I wondered had someone gave me these tips, how many man hours it would have saved